# Which C*-algebras are complemented in their bidual?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

Every von Neumann algebra is 1-complemented in its bidual, and so is every injective C*-algebra. Also, if $C_0(X)$ is infinite-dimensional and separable then it is not complemented in its bidual, and $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$ is not complemented in its bidual when $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite-dimensional.

How much more than this is known? Is every infinite-dimensional separable C*-algebra not complemented in its bidual? Is anything known about the nonseparable case?

Comment: Cameron, what does 1-complemented mean?

Comment: It means complemented with a projection of norm 1.

Comment: Every dual Banach space is 1-complemented in its bidual.

Answer (score 8):

(1) If $A$ is $1$-complemented in its bidual, then $A$ is an AW*-algebra.

Indeed, assume that $A$ is $1$-complemented in its bidual, via a contractive projection $p\colon A^{**}\to A$. By a theorem of Tomiyama, $p$ is a conditional expectation. This implies that $A$ is monotone closed, that is, every upward directed family of self-adjoint elements in $A$ has a supremum. In particular, $A$ is an AW*-algebra. (A C*-algebra is an AW*-algebra if every maximal abelian $*$-subalgebra is monotone complete, see [1].)

(2) Every separable AW*-algebra is finite-dimensional.

Indeed, assume $A$ is a separable AW*-algebra. Consider a maximal abelian $*$-subalgebra (=masa) $B$ of $A$. Then $B\cong C(X)$ for some compact, Hausdorff, extremally disconnected space $X$ (such spaces are also called Stonean). Every metrizable, extremally disconnected space is discrete. Therefore, $X$ is finite. Thus, every masa in $A$ is finite-dimensional. This implies that $A$ is finite-dimensional. (Every infinite-dimensional C*-algebra contains a positive element with infinite spectrum, and hence an infinite-dimensional masa.)

Combining (1) and (2) we obtain that a separable, infinite-dimensional C*-algebra is never $1$-complemented in its bidual.

[1] arxiv.org/abs/1501.02434

Comment: That separable, infinite-dimensional C*-algebras are never complemented in their biduals (with any constant) follows also from an earlier result of Pfitzner that von Neumann algebras are Grothendieck spaces.

Comment: I see, that is a much more direct and more general argument. Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that only for C*-algebras that are 1-complemented in the second dual we may say something definite (they are AW*-algebras as observed by Hannes).

A separable C*-algebra $A$ that is complemented in $A^{**}$ must be finite-dimensional, as by [a result of Pfitzner](https://eudml.org/doc/165175), it is a Grothendieck space. It is an easy exercise on [the Eberlein–Šmulian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem) that a separable Grothendieck space is reflexive. [Reflexive C*-algebras are finite-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554408/finite-dimensional-c-algebras).

Beyond this case we cannot say much more even in the commutative case. For example, kernels of non-weak*-continuous characters on $\ell_\infty$ are complemented in their biduals (being Banach-space isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$). The question of for which (locally) compact space $K$ the space $C_0(K)$ is isomorphic to a dual space (such spaces are complemented in their second duals) is discussed in the [forthcoming book](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783319323473) by Dales, [Dashiell](https://mathoverflow.net/users/20300/fred-dashiell), Lau and Strauss. Even in this case, the current state of affairs it far from a complete characterisation. Indeed, it is still open whether injective Banach spaces are isomorphic to 1-injectives ones (that is, to commutative AW*-algebras) and a commutative C*-algebra complemented in the second dual is injective.

Comment: Hannes only said that a C*-algebra that is 1-complemented in its bidual must be monotone complete, not that every monotone complete algebra is 1-complemented in its bidual. I couldn't find any evidence of the converse by searching online, but maybe it's known. And if we knew that every AW*-algebra was 1-complemented in its bidual then we would know that every AW*-algebra is monotone complete.

Comment: Every injective C*-algebra is monotone complete (for the reason noted by Hannes), but not every monotone complete C*-algebra is injective, e.g. any non-injective von Neumann algebra.